# Why does the following Fortran code allocate on the stack/heap depending on the contents of a derived type?

Tags: memory-management, fortran, gfortran

I do not understand why the following program segfaults with a SIGSEGV if the `bar` field is present in `containerType`, and works without problems if it is commented out. I'm on x86_64, compiling with both gfortran-4.4.6 and gfortran-4.6.3.

As I understand it, using a pointer to `containerType` should force the allocation of the contained big array to happen on the heap but that doesn't seem to be the case. Running `valgrind` on the executable gives me

```
Warning: client switching stacks?  SP change: 0x7ff000448 --> 0x7fe0603f8
         to suppress, use: --max-stackframe=16384080 or greater
```

(The rest of the output is IMHO not relevant, but I could edit it in if required). This indicates to me that there's a stack overflow; presumably due to allocating the 8*8*8*4000 * 8(bytes per real) = 16384000 bytes on the stack.

When I comment out the `bar` field, `valgrind` is perfectly happy. To make matters *even* stranger, compiling under gfortran-4.6.3 with '-O' also makes the problem go away (but not under gfortran-4.4.6).

Either I've stumbled on a compiler bug, or (more likely, as I'm pretty new to Fortran) I don't understand where data is allocated. Could someone enlighten me what's going on?

---

The code in question:

main.f90:

```
program main 

    use problematicArray
    implicit none    
    type (containerType),pointer :: container
    allocate(container)

    container%foo%arrayData = 17.0
    write(*,*) container%foo%arrayData(7,7,7,100)
    deallocate(container)
    write(*,*) 'Program finished'

end program main
```

problematicArray.f90:

```
module problematicArray
    implicit none
    private

    integer, parameter, public :: dim1 = 4000 

    type, public :: typeWith4DArray
        real(8), dimension(8,8,8,dim1) ::  arrayData 
    end type typeWith4DArray

    type :: typeWithChars
        character(4), dimension(:), allocatable :: charData
    end type typeWithChars

    type, public :: containerType
        type(typeWith4DArray) :: foo
        type(typeWithChars) :: bar
    end type containerType

end module problematicArray
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This must be a bug in gfortran. I do not see anything wrong there. It also works in Intel and Oracle compilers. Best to report it to gfortran developers. I tried it with only a 2 days old build of the `gfortran 4.8` trunk.

The error has nothing to do with stack/heap difference. It simply crashes during the `allocate` statement. It does not even work with `stat=` and `errmsg=` set.

Just a note, you can have the module and the main program inside a single source file.

Comment: I reported the possible issue as http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56471

Comment: Thanks for verifying this a bug, saving my sanity, and for filing the bug report - I don't know the proper channels, so this is much appreciated. I'll work around the bug for now (by introducing a couple of POINTERs here and there).